# Visual Studio Glew

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I have a problem.

I'm learning OpenGL and I want to draw a triangle.
But it does'nt work.

Error Messages:

LNK1120 1 unresolved externals

LNK2019 Reference to unresolved external symbol"__imp__glDrawArrays@12" in function ""void __cdecl draw(void)" (?draw@@YAXXZ)".

Code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>

GLuint vertexBuffer;

void initDraw() {
    GLuint vertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);

    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data),
    g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void draw() {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

Sorry for the bad english, especially for the error messages. My IDE show me the errors in german and I must translate this.

Comment: You will need to link opengl32.lib, glew32.lib (and maybe build glew first)

Comment: I have linked glew32.lib, but which opengl32.lib? (I have built glew)

Comment: Windows comes with opengl32.lib.

Comment: In which directory is this lib?

Comment: It's somewhere in a system directory. Visual Studio will already have the path so you only need to add "opengl32.lib" to the linker input

Comment: Thanks, it's work! But I don't see a triangle.

Comment: You should ask a new question and show there all necessary code.